# How do I position a circlular div halfway over an angled div?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms

I am currently trying to build a portfolio website. Here is my landing page idea:

[image]

The part that I am struggling with regarding this design is positioning the down arrow so that it straddles the angled div regardless of screen width.

The closest that I have been able to come is by assigning the following values to the button...

```
position: absolute;
top: 290px;
left: 30%;
```

Here is my code:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.bg-hero {
    background: #00C1F7;
    position: relative;
}

.bg-dark {
    background: #003342;
    position: relative;
}

.angled-div::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.button {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 290px;
    left: 30%;
    background: #003342;
    border-radius: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.button span {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 62px;
}

.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #004472
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-hero"></section>

<div class="button"><span>&darr;</span></div>
<section class="bg-dark angled-div"></section>
```

**Question**

How do I position my div so that it is halfway over the angled div and remains exactly half way over the angled div no matter the screen width?

Comment: My sincerest apologies Paulie, i thought I would get away with a link to CodePen. I will make sure to stick to the rules in the future. Thanks.

Comment: No problem but I think JS is the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a near *perfect* centering if you can change your markup:

1. Change the *skewed* pseudo element to a `span` and position the `button` *inside* the `span` so that the `button` is also *skewed*.
2. Center the `button` using the below and also make a *reverse* skew:

   ```
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -100%) skew(3deg);
   transform-origin: left bottom;
   ```
3. Now make the contents of the `button` vertical using `transform: rotate(3deg)` on the `button span` element.
4. Now you can change the value of `top` (say 50px) to push the `button` inside the *skewed* section as much as needed.

See demo below:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.bg-hero {
    background: #00C1F7;
    position: relative;
}

.bg-dark {
    background: #003342;
    position: relative;
}

.angled-div > span{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.button {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) skew(3deg);
    background: #003342;
    border-radius: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.button span {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 62px;
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}

.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #004472;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-hero"></section>
<section class="bg-dark angled-div">
  <span>
    <div class="button"><span>&darr;</span></div>
  </span>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow, just wow... that is a genius level solution! Definitely going to refer back to this one. Thank you so much!